# TYPO3 powermail define bootstrap col-md-12

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I have a TYPO3 website with latest powermail plugin.

all inputfiels got `col-md-6` as css class

I want that they all have `col-md-12` wheren can I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation of powermail: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Faq/Index.html#how-can-i-use-responsive-columns-in-powermail
Classes can be changed via TypoScript.

For example, from the manual:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup {
    styles {
        numberOfColumns = 2
        framework {
            rowClasses = row
            fieldAndLabelWrappingClasses = form-group col-md-6
        }
    }
}
```